# How to get the selected values in a DataGrid with React Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datagrid

I'm working with a React MUI DataGrid. I need to get the values of the selected rows. At the moment, only the ids are coming through, and I get several errors throughout.

```
rows = data;

const columns = [
  {
    field: "id",
    headerName: "ID",
    sortable: false,
    hide: true,
  },
  {
    field: "firstName",
    headerName: "First Name",
  },
  {
    field: "lastName",
    headerName: "Last Name",
  },
  {
    field: "age",
    headerName: "Age",
  }
];
```

This is my React Hook.

```
const [ selection, setSelection ] = useState<GridSelectionModel>([]);
```

And this is the DataGrid.

```
<div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
     <DataGrid
      rows={rows}
      columns={columns}
      checkboxSelection
      getRowId={(row) => row.id}
      onSelectionModelChange={(newSelection) => {
              setSelection(newSelection);
              console.log("selection", selection)
            }}
      {...rows}
/>
</div>
```

This prints the id.

```
<p>{selection.map((data) => data)}</p>
```

But, what I need, and I'm not able to figure out is:

```
{selection.map((data) => {
     return (
        <div key={data.id}>. <---ERROR
          <p>{data.firstName}</p> <---ERROR
          <p>{data.lastName}</p> <---ERROR
        </div>
       )
     })}
```

When I do it this way, I get the following error: "Property does not exist on type 'GridRowId'."

Comment: Seems like `selection` is an array of selected IDs. You can probably look up with data by comparing back with its ID.

Comment: @junwen-k Would you happen to have an example? I'm not quite sure how to accomplish that. I've tried filtering through the rows, but it seems I always end up with a new error message.

Comment: Do you mind providing a minimal reproducible example on CodeSandbox? That way it will be easier for me to provide an answer.

Comment: @junwen-k Hi! I created a CodeSandbox. It's my first time setting one up. It does display an error, but I set up the files like the code above. You can view here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-sound-wh4l3k?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi, did you forget to save your latest changes on your Sandbox? The Sandbox looks incomplete.

Comment: @junwen-k So sorry about that! I thought it auto-saved. Let me know if this works for you. I opened it in a different browser to make sure it was there: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-danny-nc9nn0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: No need to apologize! I'll provided an answer based on some assumption on your data. Let me know if it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selection` will be an array of IDs instead of an array of items. You can remap the IDs back to your items, E.g,

`data.json`

```json
[
  {
    "id": "id-001",
    "firstName": "First Name 1",
    "lastName": "Last Name 1",
    "age": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "id-002",
    "firstName": "First Name 2",
    "lastName": "Last Name 2",
    "age": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "id-003",
    "firstName": "First Name 3",
    "lastName": "Last Name 3",
    "age": 3
  },
  {
    "id": "id-004",
    "firstName": "First Name 4",
    "lastName": "Last Name 4",
    "age": 4
  },
  {
    "id": "id-005",
    "firstName": "First Name 5",
    "lastName": "Last Name 5",
    "age": 5
  }
]
```

`App.tsx`

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { DataGrid, GridSelectionModel } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import data from "./data.json";

const columns = [
  {
    field: "id",
    headerName: "ID",
    sortable: false,
    hide: true
  },
  {
    field: "firstName",
    headerName: "First Name"
  },
  {
    field: "lastName",
    headerName: "Last Name"
  },
  {
    field: "age",
    headerName: "Age"
  }
];

// NOTE: Pulls in imported json data.
const rows = data;

export default function App() {
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState<GridSelectionModel>([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
        <DataGrid
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          checkboxSelection
          gridRowId={(row) => row.id}
          onSelectionModelChange={setSelection}
          {...rows}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        {selection
          .map((selectedId) => data.find((item) => item.id === selectedId))
          .map(({ id, firstName, lastName }) => (
            <div key={id}>
              <p>{firstName}</p>
              <p>{lastName}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit 74426054]

Comment: I gave this a try. I get an error in the <div> in ```data.find``` It states "Cannot find name data." I changed it to ```rows.find``` and it fixed the error there, but then where the properties are deconstructed (```.map(({ id, firstName, lastName})``` I get the following error: "Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ id: string; firstName: string; "...

Comment: @Juanita May I check your `data.json`? Cause in your Sandbox `data.json` is empty. By following the example that I've provided it should work :)

Comment: ```[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Sally",
    "lastName": "Michaels", 
    "age": 10
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "Jen",
    "lastName": "Samuel",
    "age": 12
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "firstName": "Roger",
    "lastName": "Richardson",
    "age": 15
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "firstName": "Mike",
    "lastName": "Johnson",
    "age": 16
  }
]```

Comment: Would it be a typescript issue?

Comment: @Juanita Supposedly `id` exists in your property type. You might need to double check and compare your code with my Sandbox to see what is the difference. I've updated the Sandbox to use your `data,json`'s content and it worked.

Comment: Just realized I have to save every page. I saved and now the json data appears here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-danny-nc9nn0?file=/package.json

Comment: I'm wondering if it is a typescript issue. Can you share your CodeSandbox link?

Comment: @Juanita Hi, the Sandbox link is already shared in the answer ya. Just look at the bottom you should see a button "Edit on CodeSandbox". You can also access the Sandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/74426054-g1go69?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Comment: That looks like it works. I'm going to see if I am able to sort out the TypeScript issue and will get back to you. I really appreciate all the time you took to help me sort through this.

Comment: I figured out the TypeScript issue! I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

For those using TypeScript, adding the following allowed the accepted code above to work.

Added "GridColDef[]" type.

```
const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  {
    field: "id",
    headerName: "ID",
    sortable: false,
    hide: true
  },
  {
    field: "firstName",
    headerName: "First Name"
  },
  {
    field: "lastName",
    headerName: "Last Name"
  },
  {
    field: "age",
    headerName: "Age"
  }
];
```

And adding a type of "any" where I'm pulling in the data.

```
const rows: any = data;
```